# attempt to index nil with 'Value'

Tags: roblox-studio

I am trying to make a tycoon in roblox  but it said:

Workspace.Tycoons.Tycoon.MainItems.ConveyorBelt.CashPart.Script:5: attempt to index nil with 'Value'

This is my script:

```
local values = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Values
script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
    if hit.Name == "DropperPart" and hit:IsA("BasePart") then
        values.MoneyValue.Value += hit:FindFirstChild("CashValue").Value
        hit:Destroy()
    end
end)
```

and this is line 5:
values.MoneyValue.Value += hit:FindFirstChild("CashValue").Value

i tried fixing it but i can't can someone help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s saying it’s nil which means it probably doesn’t know the child exists, so you can’t access its value. Try this:

```
local values = script.Parent.Parent.Parent.Parent.Values

script.Parent.Touched:Connect(function(hit)
local cashValue = hit:FindFirstChild("CashValue")

if hit.Name == "DropperPart" and hit:IsA("BasePart") and cashValue then
    values.MoneyValue.Value += cashValue.Value
    hit:Destroy()
end
end)
```